# Is there an implementation of MarshalURLQuery for Go?

Tags: go, marshalling

Given a Go struct like this:

```
type Color struct {
    Red   int32 `url:"red"`
    Green int32 `url:"green"`
    Blue  int32 `url:"blue"`
    Alpha int32 `url:"alpha,omitempty"`
}
```

it would be great to be able to turn it into a URL query, like:

```
c := Color{
    Red:   255,
    Green: 127,
}

v, err := MarshalURLQuery(c)

fmt.Printf("%s", string(b))
```

where v is a `url.Values` instance, yielding "`red=255&green=127&blue=0`". Surely Go must already provide something like this. How do I do this in Go without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I edited the question as requested. Is there a process for requesting a review in order to possibly reopen the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [gorilla/schema](http://%5Bhttps://github.com/gorilla/schema%5D(gorilla/schema)), using the `encoder`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"

    "github.com/gorilla/schema"
)

type Person struct {
    Name     string `schema:"name"`
    Lastname string `schema:"lastname"`
}

func main() {

    person := &Person{Name: "John", Lastname: "Doe"}
    encoder := schema.NewEncoder()

    v2 := url.Values{}
    if err := encoder.Encode(person, v2); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(v2.Encode())
}
```

Output:

```sh
lastname=Doe&name=John
```

- https://play.golang.org/p/0_7879f5BES